# Wi-Fi Monitor mode listening to traffic

Tags: networking, wifi, tcpdump

Can we broadcast Music using wifi broadcast and listen to thhe same on devices supporting monitor mode. 
I would like to listen on monitor mode because I expect the number of devices getting connected is too high for wifi to work properly using IP-protocol.
I want the wifi device to act as a FM broadcast where every device recieves every packets and stream the music.

Comment: Wi-Fi is not a layer-3 (IP) protocol, it is a layer-2 protocol. Wi-Fi will need to give time to any other Wi-Fi devices, no matter what, since that is built into the Wi-Fi standards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you talking about [this Wifibroadcast](https://befinitiv.wordpress.com/wifibroadcast-analog-like-transmission-of-live-video-data/) , [here](https://bitbucket.org/befi/wifibroadcast)?

If so: well **yes**, monitor mode is the underlying technology, as can be seen [here](https://befinitiv.wordpress.com/wifibroadcast-analog-like-transmission-of-live-video-data/wifibroadcast-fpv-manual-setup/).

Now, if this is about doing a commercial product, sadly, you cannot expect any kind of interoperability from this.

Streaming audio/video over Wi-Fi is a *business*, and the the power in charge ([Wi-Fi Alliance aka WFA](http://www.wi-fi.org/)) as some view on it, including certification programs. Have a look at [Miracast, using Wi-Fi Direct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miracast).

As for multicast / broadcast, it is even *more* of a business and the realm of proprietary technologies for now (example [here](http://www.cinemo.com/solutions/multimedia-playback-streaming.html) - and no, this is not limited to automobile). This is quite complicated, to start with because of the synchronization problem across receivers: you don't want 2 radio receivers in the same room to play with a 1 seconds delay, this would be cacophony.

EDIT:

Meaning, be it with the Wifibroadcast OSS project or with the proprietary industry about it, since there is not yet an open protocol for this (as "publicly available standard specification", I don't even go about implementation, FLOSS or not), ***you* will have to provide *a specific application for every receiver* to match *your* broadcaster protocol**, and vice versa. And that is the state of the industry today. That is what the company I mentioned above, or [this other one more well know](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AirPlay), or [these](http://www.harmankardon.com/wireless-hd-speakers/) are doing. **And so, they do not interoperate. This will be your problem:** provide a receiver app for Windows, Mac OS, Android and iOS (where you may not even have access to sub-layer 3 API) that will match your radio broadcaster protocol. And Linux too, please.

**Though, this is the direction of history because this is what the user wants: stream A/V to/from device/application X from brand A to device/application Y from brand B.**

And so people have been working on this, on layer 2, because layer 3 and above have unsolvable challenges with it, at IEEE since 2004 with [Ethernet AVB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audio_Video_Bridging), which is a set of protocols. You can download some of its standards for free, others for a moderate fee depending on how old they are. There is a [SIG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_Interest_Group) taking care of certification(http://avnu.org/certified-products/) to guarantee interoperability.

It is for 802.3 (aka wired Ethernet), but [there is some work done to bring this to 802.11 Wi-Fi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audio_Video_Bridging#IEEE_802.11_.2F_Wireless_LAN). Because again, that's what the user wants, the market is here, no question about that. It will take a *long* time. Even more to get consumer electronic grade devices or applications of the shelves. **But they will interoperate out of the box, that's the goal.**

There's even been work done on moving this [to layer 3/IP as well](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1733-2011.html) BTW, with some performance sacrifice.

So come back in a few years, and all should be setup. Or, if you have lots of time and money and no urge to deliver, implement a solution based on these standards?

PS:

Link to AVnu (Ethernet AVB SIG) page about use cases for consumer electronics audio streaming, wired or wireless:

http://avnu.org/consumer/

...and its 10 pages white paper at the bottom of the page.